# "vor Langer Weile" - veraltet, Tippfehler oder ein Wortspiel?

Tags: spelling

In "Buddenbrooks" (5. Teil, 9):

> "Unsinn, Tony! Du mit deinem Leben... Aber wir langweilen uns wohl ziemlich stark?"
>
> "Ja, Tom, ich langweile mich ganz ungemein. Manchmal heule ich **vor Langer Weile**."

Warum wird hier "vor Langer Weile" geschrieben? (und *Langer* auch großgeschrieben)

Comment: Also in meiner Ausgabe steht: „Manchmal heule ich vor Langerweile.“ Daher gehe ich davon aus, dass Sie eine ältere Ausgabe haben, in der der Druckfehler noch nicht korrigiert wurde.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich ok, obwohl "Langerweile" auch nicht ganz richtig ist :) Mein Buch ist 2011, aber die Erstausgabe war 1960 oder 1974 (ich weiss nicht wie ich die Angabe "(c) 1960 / 1974" deuten soll)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich und @ Eller: In der Originalausgabe (S. Fischer, Berlin 1901) heißt es tatsächlich "vor Langer Weile" ([1. Bd. S. 429](https://digital.staatsbibliothek-berlin.de/werkansicht?PPN=PPN1670669289&PHYSID=PHYS_0433)). Ein Druckfehlerverzeichnis konnte ich in keinem der beiden Bände ausfindig machen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"Langerweile"* wird im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Langeweile) als Nebenform des Dativs von Langeweile aufgeführt, ebenso wird im Genitiv die Form *"Langenweile"* genannt.

Im [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Langeweile) steht dagegen:

> Hinweis: *bei Beugung des ersten Bestandteils wird getrennt geschrieben:* das Ende der Langeweile; aber: das Ende der langen Weile; aus Langeweile; aber: aus langer Weile.

Ich finde die Duden-Logik hier deutlich nachvollziehbarer. Wenn man Langeweile auf diese Weise beugt, dann doch wohl aus dem Verständnis heraus, dass es sich eigentlich/ursprünglich um eine "lange Weile" handelt, die eine Spezialbedeutung bekommen hat. Und dann ist die Schreibung "langer Weile" bzw. "langen Weile" logischer als die Schreibungen "Langenweile" bzw. "Langerweile", die nicht Fleisch und nicht Fisch sind.

Thomas Mann hat mit "Langer Weile" (mit großen L) offenbar eine noch andere Zwischenform benutzt. Man kann das, wenn man möchte, so interpretieren, dass er "Lange Weile" als feststehenden Ausdruck à la "Erste Hilfe" begreift.

Der Widerspruch zwischen Duden und DWDS zeigt schon, dass man hier an die Grenzen der Sinnhaftigkeit einer festgezurrten Orthographie kommt. Thomas Mann, noch dazu in der direkten Rede einer Romanfigur, die eine völlig andere Sprache benutzt als der Autor, steht über sowas einfach drüber.

Comment: Bei aller dichterischen Freiheit Thomas Manns - die Schreibweise "Langer Weile" mit großen "L" ist falsch, egal ob absichtlich von ihm so geschrieben oder nicht.

Comment: @KritikerderElche Ja, aber sie ist halt "falsch" in einer Welt, in der die Schreibweise "vor Langerweile" als richtig angesehen wird. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"vor Langer Weile" mit großgeschriebenen *Langer* ist sicher falsch, es kommen aber "vor langer Weile" oder "vor Langerweile" in Frage. Die erste Variante ist absolut in Ordnung, bei der zweiten Variante könnte es sich um einen Rechtschreibfehler handeln (entweder seitens Thomas Mann oder erst beim Drucksatz entstanden). Ich vermute jedoch, dass "Langerweile" eine alte Nebenform von "Langeweile" ist. Eine Google-Suche liefert zahlreiche Treffer, u.a. findet man dieses Hörbuch:

[image]

Auch das könnte natürlich ein Fehler sein, aber an so prominenter Stelle halte ich das für unwahrscheinlich.